# How to DISTINCT if match more than one?

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to select who using multiple phone number. How to query result if phone number match more than 1?

I have tried this query below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    group,
    email,
    phone
FROM
    account
WHERE
    group = 6
GROUP BY
    phone
HAVING
    COUNT( phone ) > 1  
ORDER BY
    phone
```

```
group   email           phone
6       xxsd@adsf.xsd   003434234523
6       wet@ardsf.xsd   003434234523
6       rwwe@adsf.xsd   003364534579
6       hdgh@adsf.xsd   003434234523
```

So if phone number (003434234523) match more than 1, then query will execute.

Comment: Are you looking for users who have more than 1 phone number or phone numbers that are being used by more than 1 user?

Comment: Same phone numbers that are being used by more than 1 user. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Group is a reserved word, so this pointedly *isn't* the query you tried :-( See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Use EXISTS to find the emails of the users who use the same phone:

```
SELECT 
    a.group,
    a.email,
    a.phone
FROM
    account a
WHERE
    a.group = 6
    AND EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM account 
      WHERE group = 6 AND phone = a.phone AND email <> a.email 
    )
ORDER BY a.phone
```

I used `WHERE group = 6` because you have it in your code.

Comment: What does means by 'a' string?

Comment: It is an alias for the table `account` used to distinguish it from the same table in the subquery of EXISTS.

Comment: Does not work. I would to select a 'phone' column if the 'phone' column value is match more than 1.

Comment: In your question you say: *I would like to select who using multiple phone number*, this means that there are users which use more than 1 phone numbers and you want all these users with the phone numbers you use. If you want something else edit your question and better post sample data and expected results.

Comment: Ok, plz look my 1st post comments.

Comment: This is what my code does: `phone = a.phone AND email <> a.email` means same phone different emails.

Comment: Thanks it's working. But my question was if match more than 1 only.

Comment: What do you mean by that? You want only the phone numbers or something else?

Comment: Your code is 'phone' match more than one but also match single user. p.s. Your code query run very long. Query time 8.684s

Comment: My code returns all emails using a single phone. Why don't you post the expected results so to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

This will find all records from the account table in group 6 that use a phone number that is used by more than 1 account.

```
SELECT * 
FROM account
WHERE `group` = 6
AND phone IN (SELECT phone
              FROM account
              WHERE `group` = 6
              GROUP BY phone
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY phone;
```

Comment: Thank you its working and Query time 4.489s very fast but its also match where phone number not more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Same phone numbers that are being used by more than 1 user.

Repeated phones:

```
   SELECT phone, count(*)
   FROM account
   WHERE group = 6
   GROUP BY phone
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Emails using the repeated phones:

```
SELECT group, email, phone
FROM account
WHERE phone IN (
   SELECT phone, count(*)
   FROM account
   WHERE group = 6
   GROUP BY phone
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
ORDER BY phone
```